# can std::unordered_map::rehash() function reduce the hash collision?

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map

I encountered a algorithm problem in which timeout occurred using unordered_map in c++.

Hash maps in other languages worked fine with that problem.

So I've tried to improve the performance of unordered_map by using rehash function.
I expected to pass the problem but failed.

As I understood, rehash function would make more buckets, leading the reduction of hash collision.

So my question is rehash function can actually reduce the collision.
If so, I can conclude that the fundamental cause of timeout is in that problem.

Edited ===========
the problem is

[question]
The SUM problem can be formulated as follows: given four lists A, B, C, D of integer values, compute how many quadruplet (a, b, c, d ) ∈ A x B x C x D are such that a + b + c + d = 0 . In the following, we assume that all lists have the same size n.

[input format]
The first line of the input contains the size of the lists n (this value can be as large as 4000). We then have n lines containing four integer values (with absolute value as large as 228) that belong respectively to A, B, C and D .

and my code...

```
using namespace std;


#define SIZE 4000

int A[SIZE];
int B[SIZE];
int C[SIZE];
int D[SIZE];

int main(void){
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for(int i=0; i <N;i++){
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &A[i], &B[i], &C[i], &D[i]);
    }

    unordered_map<int, int> LeftMap; // store all result of A[i] + B[i]
    //LeftMap.rehash(1000000);
    unordered_map<int, int> RightMap; // store all result of C[i] + D[i]
    unordered_map<int, int>::iterator iter;
    unordered_map<int, int>::iterator iter2;

    int k;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
            k = A[i]+B[j];

            iter = LeftMap.find(k);
            if(iter == LeftMap.end())
                LeftMap.insert({k, 1});
            else
                iter->second++;

            k = C[i]+D[j];

            iter = RightMap.find(k);
            if(iter == RightMap.end())
                RightMap.insert({k, 1});
            else
                iter->second++;
        }
    }

    int sum =0;
    for(iter = RightMap.begin(); iter != RightMap.end(); ++iter){
        iter2 = LeftMap.find((iter->first)* -1);
        if(iter2 != LeftMap.end()){
            sum+= iter->second * iter2->second;
        }
    }

    printf("%d", sum);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you know or can estimate the number of elements in advance, you may call `std::unordered_map::reserve` when the map is empty. Rehashing is relatively expensive once there are elements in it. (Note that unordered map performs rehashing automatically for you as you add elements, which, may be avoided by `reserve`.)

Comment: Please show a [repro] of the issue. There is probably no point to manually rehash and it is likely a pessimization. Taking the current question literally the answer is probably "yes it can", but that is not going to help you with the performance of your program.

Comment: Can you paste the code with which you got the timeout? I think the timeout probably could have been due to excessive flushing because of `endl` which is why most of C++ timeouts occur in such competitions provided you already have an efficient solution.

Comment: `rehash` is generally only go to help if you are specifying more buckets (bigger hash table). Potentially you might be on the very edge where load factor is high but it didn't get enough to *automatically* rehash, or you may have a poor quality hash function for the data. Or you might have serious problems elsewhere in your code/design.

Comment: I attached my code but as @Daniel Langr said, rehash occurs automatically then my code would not be affected significantly from adding a rehash function.  I can conclude that rehash is not an issue in this problem (because it is automatically called).